# split group by two 2 by number

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I what to do group by that split the group into 2 by value:

e.g.

```
select avg(blocks),to_char(dat,'yy-mm-dd hh24'),'small'/'big'
from tab
group by to_char(dat,'yy-mm-dd hh24'), (blocks case1 >1000, case2 <=1000)
```

for table tab:

```
id      number
blocks  number
dat     date
```

table is:

```
ID  BLOCKS   DAT
--- -------  --------
1      2   14-02-19 14:01:00
2      2   14-02-19 14:02:00
3   2000   14-02-19 14:03:00
4   3000   14-02-19 14:04:00
```

result:

```
2      14-02-19 14   small
2500   14-02-19 14   big
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a `case` statement:

```
select avg(blocks), to_char(dat,'yy-mm-dd hh24')
from tab
group by to_char(dat,'yy-mm-dd hh24'),
        (case when blocks > 1000 then 1
              else 2
         end);
```

Comment: Is it efficient? Is there a better method?

Comment: @nir . . . This is quite efficient.

Comment: Thanks. I've add small thing, please see the update. Copy the `case` part from the `group by` is efficient?

Comment: @nlr . . . You don't have to worry about the efficiency of this operation, with or without the case statement in the `select` clause.